# python polarion api how to access wiki/documentations and pages

Tags: python, automation, polarion

I am trying to use this [Python library](https://python-polarion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick_start.html) to do some automation. After reading the doc, I know how to access the work item and its subdirectory but there is another same level to the work item which is `Documents & Pages` or `wiki` as stated in the URL(https://polarion.engineering.abc.com/polarion/#/project/project_name/wiki/). I wonder if there is a way to access that.
Here is what it looks like:
[image]

I can easily access everything in `Work Items` but I would also like to access `Documents & Pages` to do some export. Is there any Python lib that can do that?

Comment: Upon further *googling* it seems that the newest version of polarion does support the documents section, you linked an old version of the library, update your lib and checkout: https://python-polarion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński you're right, I was looking at the stable version. There is something for the latest. Thank you!

Comment: Anyway, I checked the document. It's only available for accessing the documents but I can't access `page`

Answer (score 0):

I found another Python library that has a feature to fetch the wiki pages from Polarion. Here is the link: https://redhatqe.github.io/pylero/

It's as simple as:

```
from pylero.wiki_page import WikiPage
wikis = WikiPage.get_wiki_pages("project_id", "space_id", [fields])
```